# Simplify the algebraic fraction

Tags: fractions, rational-functions

How to simplify the algebraic fraction
$\frac{2}{x+5} + \frac{3}{x-2} + \frac{1}{x}$

I get the answer as $\frac{2(3x^2 +7x-5)}{x(x+5)(x-2)}$

Is this right? Or how can I simplify this further?

Comment: Correct: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor(2%2F(x%2B5)+%2B+3%2F(x-2)+%2B+1%2Fx).

Answer (score 1):

That is correct and you can't simplify it further since the numerator and the denominator have no common factors. In this case, you can check that by checking that none of the three roots of the denominator ($0$, $2$, and $-5$) is also a root of the numerator.